# regex exp to detect only one occurrence of an "abc-xxx" pattern

Tags: regex, perl, regex-negation

Here are a list of strings

1. abc-1234 hi hello~abc-3456 ok~abc-4456
2. abc-1234
3. abc-2356 hi~abc-1234 ok
4. abc-1234 ok~abc-1234 hello
5. abc-1234 ok~abc-1234 hello~abc-1456 ok ok

Need to write a regex pattern that will detect if abc-1234 is the only "abc-" pattern presentand match it. If abc-1234 is present along with another abc-xxxx pattern, we should not have a match. In other words, I need to write a regex pattern to match the occurrence of abc-1234 when it's the only abc- pattern present. Note that the abc pattern is always preceeded by '~'

So in the above cases, when we try to do a match between the regex pattern and the strings, we get the following results :
1. does not match
2. matches
3. does not match
4. matches
5. does not match

Can a regex expert help me here?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason why this needs to be done entirely within the regex? This sounds like it would be much easier using some procedural code as well - e.g. match all occurrences, and discard if there are `>1`, or match one mandatory occurrence and one optional, rejecting the match if the optional part is matched.

Comment: `^abc-1234[^~]*(~abc-1234[^~]*)*$` - disappointed that you didn't show any effort.

Comment: Hi Paddy, thanks for the response. I was trying to do something with positive and negative look aheads,^(?!abc).*abc-1234.*(?!abc).*|^(abc-1234)~*.*(?!abc-).* .. but it dint work. Do you have pointers to good documentation on regex?

Answer (score 3):

Using positive-negative lookeheads:

```
use strict; use warnings;
my @s = ('abc-1234 hi hello~abc-3456 ok~abc-4456',
    'abc-1234', 'abc-2356 hi~abc-1234 ok', 'abc-1234 ok~abc-1234 hello',
    'abc-1234 ok~abc-1234 hello~abc-1456 ok ok');

for my $s (@s) {
    if ($s !~ /^abc-(\d+)(?=.*~abc-(?!\1))/) {
        print "$s\n";
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
abc-1234
abc-1234 ok~abc-1234 hello
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply.. Can you please explain (?=.*~abc-(?!\1))/) ?

Comment: match if there is a `~abc-` ahead, and it is not immediately followed by the thing after the first `abc-` capture on the line...

Comment: thanks a lot! could you point me to documentation on lookaheads?

Comment: don't really know a lot just this: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html, which is the first google result :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative look ahead anchored to start of input:

```
^(?!(.*abc-\d{4}){2}.*$)abc-\d{4}
```

Comment: This looks like the kind of regex that could easily lead to [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) or similar pathologies.

Comment: @IMSoP this won't lead to CB because there's only one variable term. To get CB you need *two* variable length but similar regexes that fails to match overall due to a following fragment but which can match in multiple combinations of consumption between them. This regex doesn't have two terms like that. It will be fine, but you can test it if you like with a large input and let me know if you find a problem.

Comment: I was looking at the inner (negated) expression - slightly simplified, it reads `(.*abc){2}.*$`. I can't quite picture what the problem input would be, but that's a lot of `.*`s that can consume different sections of the input.

Answer (score 0):

A solution in Perl using 2 regexes. It gets the count of all matches, abc-\d\d\d\d and compares that count to the count for abc-1234 matches.

```
print if  ( () = /abc-\d\d\d\d/g) ==  ( () = /abc-1234/g);
```